# Disabled textbox and ViewState woes

Tags: jquery, viewstate

I have an asp.net textbox that is disabled:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpName" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

Using jQuery, I then enable or disable the textbox depending upon two radio buttons that are clicked.

```
$(document).on("change", "input[id*='_rbtnIsFullTime_']", function ($e) {
  if ($(this).val() == "1")
    $("input[id$='_txtEmpName']").removeAttr('disabled');
  else
    $("input[id$='_txtEmpName']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

The problem that I am running into is when the textbox is enabled via jQuery, any text that is then entered into it by the user is not submitted with the page because the ViewState still shows the textbox as being disabled when the page was originally rendered.

Any ideas on how to get around this and make the ViewState play nicely with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a second textbox with the same text and make ti disabled. Then just toggle the visibility of the two boxes accordingly?

Comment: interesting idea... could do the same with a hidden field too i suppose... thanks for the help

Comment: Sure. Either of those two will work. Either mirroring the text into a hidden input or hidden textarea. You get the idea tho